# How to use output of one .tf file as a input different .tf file in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 folders named repo and ECS. Inside the repo folder, I have defined repo.tf in which I am giving an output of my repo URI...Now I want to use that output in ecs.tf file which is in the ECS folder? Is there any possibility?

Comment: Might be useful. https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-use-one-modules-variable-in-another-module-in-terraform/

Comment: You need to provide one details? These are two modules of same project, or totally independent projects? Do you have any concrete code example of your setup?

Comment: Are "repo" and "ECS" separate Terraform projects or the same project? Which resources specifically you want to "link" using the output? Sometimes there are other options etc. Please add more details.

Comment: I have main project under which 2 different folders having terraform file... Now repo folder is having repo.tf(which on executing makes ecr repo) file and ECS folder having ecs.tf file (which on executing makes elastic container service) ... Now I have given output of my repouri in repo.tf which I need to use in ecs.tf... So how can I do that? If I try to use module concept then it fails due to conflict.